# Display whole image as a thumbnail without cropping

Tags: php

In this code how can I change the thumbnail size center to 240 x 240 size thumbnail from image full fit?

```
<?php

$directory = 'images';

$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_parts=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;

$dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
{
    if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;

    $file_parts = explode('.',$file);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));

    $title = implode('.',$file_parts);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

    $nomargin='';

    if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
    {
        if(($i+1)%4==0) $nomargin='nomargin';

        echo '
        <div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url('.$directory.'/'.$file.') no-repeat 50% 50% ;">
        <a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
        </div>';

        $i++;
    }
}

closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `background-size` property in css,

`background: color position size repeat origin clip attachment image;`

```
 background-size:240px 240px;
```

CSs:

```
<style>
    .thumbnail{     
        background-repeat:no-repeat;         
        background-size:240px 240px;
        background-position:center; 
    }

</style>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php    
    echo '
        <div class="pic thumbnail '.$nomargin.'" style="background-image:url('.$directory.'/'.$file.');">
            <a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
        </div>';

 ?>
```